# VS Code: disable the Refresh SObject Definitions prompt

Tags: vs-code

In VS Code, how do I disable the "You don't have any sObjects cached locally" prompt?  I don't want to use this feature in my projects.

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't disable this feature completely. You can only choose either the prompt or automatic refresh on startup.